# How to determine order in Interaction collection between members?

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, mongodb-query, nosql

I have decided to have an `interaction` collection to hold the interactions between members of my App. Who blocked who, who liked who, who followed who, etc.

The schema will look something like this:

```
{
   mem_1: user_id,
   mem_2: user_id,
   mem_1_blocked_mem_2: "boolean",
   mem_2_blocked_mem_1: "boolean",
   etc...
}
```

The problem is, how is it decided, which member should be in the `mem_1` field and which should be in the `mem_2` field?

And then, when it comes to queries, how do I know which field is who?

Answer (score 1):

This might be the worst design I have seen ever.

I would suggest this:

```
{
   userId: "user1",
   blocked: ["user2", "user3"],
   liked: ["user5"]
},
{
   userId: "user2",
   blocked: ["user3"],
   liked: ["user1"]
}
```

If you like to speed up your design and if you don't care about redundancies, you can extend also by this:

```
{
   userId: "user1",
   blocked: ["user2", "user3"],
   liked: ["user5"],
   blocked_by: [],
   liked_by: ["user5", "user2"]
},
{
   userId: "user2",
   blocked: ["user3"],
   liked: ["user1"]
   blocked_by: ["user1"],
   liked_by: []
}
```

Comment: I have considered the design in your answer. But it is expected that each user will interact with many many other users, causing their document to exceed 16mb.

Comment: Really? Assume each user has a size of 16 Bytes. This means a user needs to have 1 million(!) likes or blocks in order to reach this limit. This is really a lot, even for big apps like Facebook or Instagram. And based on this (and many others) questions, it rather looks like you have not written even a single line of code for your application but you already consider millions of users.

Comment: Consider Youtube for example, it is not difficult to imagine a video getting millions of views, channel with millions of subscribers, etc.

Comment: In your design, if the document size exceeds 16MB, is it just a matter of adding another document in the same collection?

Comment: That would be no problem, of course.

Comment: Let's suppose that there are 500k elements in the `blocked` list. Each time the user logs in, I need to display to them a list of suggested users. This means that I would need to check each suggested user against this 500k-length array. This would be really slow. How can this be made faster? Or is there an alternative design?

Comment: Calculate the list of suggested users offline, not when the user is connecting. And I really doubt any user would ever block 500k other users. And again, your application will start with a few users only. Maybe after a few years it may have a couple of thousand users. Don't waste too much time on that topic already today.

Comment: "Calculate the list of suggested users offline". So I would need to store this list for every user on some other collection? Do you believe that's would Apps like YouTube does with their suggested videos?

Comment: Actually, it is not difficult to  imagine a blocked list becoming large quickly. Imagine a dating app like Tinder. It is expected that the user will either block or like a suggestion everytime.

Comment: Do you seriously compare your (not yet existing app) with giant apps like YouTube or Tinder? You should be little more realistic.

Comment: But if possible, why shouldn't I design my schema the right way now instead of having to refactor it when I get to a certain scale?

Comment: btw, could you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75054458/how-to-use-a-variable-defined-in-let-as-property-name-of-an-object-field-in-the to see if a solution is possible?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-use-a-variable-defined-in-let-as-property-name-of-an-object-field-in-the-pipeline-in-a-lookup/207769/4 here is a more detailed conversaition on the same problem